# coveralls doesn't recognize token when dockerized django app is run in TravisCI, but only from pull requests

Tags: django, docker, travis-ci, pull-request, coveralls

I'm getting [this error from TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/github/timberline-secondary/hackerspace/jobs/679417571) when it tries to run a Pull Request

> ```
> coveralls.exception.CoverallsException: Not on TravisCI. You have to provide either repo_token in .coveralls.yml or set the COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN env var.
>
> The command "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml run -e COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN web sh -c "coverage run ./src/manage.py test src && flake8 src && coveralls"" exited with 1.
> ```

However, I do have both `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` and `repo_token` set as environment variables in my TravisCI, and I know they're correct because [TravisCI passes my develop branch](https://travis-ci.org/github/timberline-secondary/hackerspace/builds/679318895) and successfully sends the results to coveralls.io:

```
OK

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Submitting coverage to coveralls.io...

Coverage submitted!

Job ##40.1

https://coveralls.io/jobs/61852774

The command "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml run -e COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN web sh -c "coverage run ./src/manage.py test src && flake8 src && coveralls"" exited with 0.
```

How do I get TravisCI to recognize my COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN for the pull requests it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: You can't! At least not while keeping your coveralls.io token secret, because:

[Defining encrypted variables in .travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml)

> Encrypted environment variables are not available to pull requests
>   from forks due to the security risk of exposing such information to
>   unknown code.

[Defining Variables in Repository Settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-variables-in-repository-settings)

> Similarly, we do not provide these values to untrusted builds,
>   triggered by pull requests from another repository.